# asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using `Asp.net dropdownlist` in one of my form ..I have two dropdown lists state,city.
My requirement is that i need to populate city dropdown list on the basis of state dropdown list...ie cities of appropriate state should be displayed.
So i have set `autopostback=true` for state dropdown list and `ontextchanged event` of state dropdown , im calling my function which populates city dropdown..
Is it the correct way ,,, or is there any other way to do this.
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the first dropdown to check for selected value & databind your 2nd dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1):

The proper event for populating the second Dropdown is the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the first Dropdown.

Comment: ,,, did u mean selectedindexchanged ,,, coz i cannot find onselecteditemchanged event in asp.net